# add working url into pdf, using qt + qprinter

Tags: c++, html, qt, pdf-generation

Is there a simple way to add a working/clikable url into a pdf, using c++, qt and the qprinter class? To clarify it a little bit: I want to add the url during generating a new document. I'm not trying to edit an existing pdf.

Comment: Not really, but they already did the neccessary work for generating pdf from URLs in this project http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: the issues is to insert simple urls into an pdf, not generating a pdf from a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a PDF with Qprinter using QTextDocument. QTextDocument has [setHtml()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextdocument.html#setHtml) method which lets you use html tags including `<a>` tag (`<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>`). After that, you can create PDF with that HTML using QTextDocument [print()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextdocument.html#print) method.

Code Example:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("out.pdf");

QTextDocument document;
QString html = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>";
document.setHtml(html);

document.print( &printer );
```

After running this code you will have out.pdf file with a clickable text: "google" that links to "http://www.google.com"

P.S. You could even add an image using `<img>` tag.

Comment: obviously for spamming it into the C++ chat room? Anyways, I like the answer, +1 from me. But don't spam again :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, no. Qt doesn't have any classes for editing PDFs, and I'm not quite sure what you'd do with QPrinter. All QPrinter can do is generate new PDFs given a non-PDF source. PDFs are very nearly write-only. The format is proprietary and quite complicated, so in the free software world it is quite rare to see any sort of code that can do editing to PDFs beyond page reordering or other simple metadata changes. If you're trying to edit an existing PDF, you're most likely on your own.